# Free SMS API in web application

Tags: api, sms

Does anyone know of any SMS APIs that I can use in my web application to send SMS messages to users?

Comment: @ColinPickard broken link?

Comment: You should try smschef. Here's the API documentation: https://smschef.com/system/api

Comment: One of the best SMS API https://www.creativepoint.in/low-cost-bulk-sms-service-provider-in-coimbatore.html

Comment: Here's a free SMS API for developers that I found: [snapisms.io](https://snapisms.io/)?

Answer (score 22):

Most mobile providers support [SNPP (Simple Network Paging Protocol)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Paging_Protocol). Despite the name, SNPP is also used to send text messages to cell phones. It's really easy to use. Just determine which mobile provider each user is using and then dispatch a "page" to the corresponding SNPP server.

For example, Sprint's SNPP server is **snpp.messaging.sprint.com:444**. The basic process goes like this:

1. Open a connection to the SNPP server.
2. Send **PAGE *The phone number***
3. Check for status code **250** in the reply.
4. Send **MESS *Your message***
5. Check for status code **250** in the reply.
6. Send **SEND**
7. Again, check for status code **250**
8. Send **QUIT**

Some servers also support subject lines and delayed messages, along with two-way messaging.

Comment: this is super interesting... the only problem is, so many different providers means lots of messiness with registration with your users.

Comment: True. You would have to ask them which carrier they are using, as I can't find any kind of API to resolve a phone number to a carrier. Could have sworn there was one, though...

Comment: How does one "open a connection"? Like a web connection? I am missing something.

Comment: dc2: A TCP/IP connection. You can also connect to an SNPP server interactively using Telnet. This answer might be outdated, though. I don't know how many carriers continue to support SMS via SNPP.

Comment: Between step 1 and step 2 you have to authenticate, of course :)

Comment: @IanEllis Authentication is an optional SNPP extension and, at least when I wrote this answer, Sprint's server didn't require it. I've not tested it since then.

Comment: Wasn't criticising David :)

Comment: Didn't say you were. :) I was just clarifying for future readers that authentication is not necessarily required to use SNPP.

Comment: @DavidBrown, Google, "cell carrier from number".  A list of websites comes up including http://www.freecarrierlookup.com/ which worked on my cell number.

Answer (score 4):

I think you may have a problem here...

SMS's always end up costing someone, something... You may get lucky and find a provider that has a beta or test account that allows you to send out a handful, but they may not last that long.

I used to use a place that put a 20 character advert on the end of every message, but even they stopped.

Just did a quick google for you and could not come up with any... If you are more specific such as country, you may get better answers...

edit - Just seen someone else answering with a site that looks good! - My comment is based on the UK! I am still not aware of any free provider here.

Answer (score 4):

They're not free, but without a doubt the best supplier I've worked with is Clickatell
http://www.clickatell.com/

They're in over 200 countries, 800 networks and their pricing is quite reasonable. They support REST HTTP/S, SOAP HTTP, FTP, SMTP, SMPP. They also support premium rate messages and MMS to generate revenue.

Comment: I had a problem with Clickatell and nobodoy reply to me. I don't recommend