# Simple Point on SMS API Communications

Tags: api, sms, request

I am a web developer, and I am confused.

Trying to make use of sprint.com's [SNPP Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Paging_Protocol), snpp.messaging.sprint.com.

I look up SNPP in 40 different places. It says its simple. It says you connect on Port 444. Simple.

[Here's Sprint's super clear, authoritative 8 page document on the subject.](https://community.sprint.com/baw/docs/DOC-2941)

[In this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203860/free-sms-api-in-web-application), David Brown explains how this is very simple and (almost) exactly how to do it.

So... my only question is... how do I connect?

Maybe i'm being totally dumb... but can I connect via a *web request* to that port? Do I use a particular HTTP verb? Or is it some lower lever request that I have to make from my web server?

I feel very dumb but i'm actually quite stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to open a TCP socket to port 444. How to do that depends on the language you're using, for example: [fsockopen](http://de3.php.net/manual/de/function.fsockopen.php) in PHP, the [socket](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html?highlight=socket#socket) module in Python or [system.net.sockets.socket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/system.net.sockets.socket) in .net. Then you proceed to send the lines from the response, ending each with a line feed (`\n`). If you'd like, you can play with the protocol without having to program a client using [Telnet in Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/978779/de) or [netcat](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/nc/) in Linux/Unix. Just run the program with server/port as arguments, depending on which you use separated by a colon (`:`), as in the original post, or a whitespace.

Comment: Aha! Thanks. That makes more sense. I'm using Node and it looks like the 'net' module totally supports communication through TCP sockets. I'll play with it.